# on Rails, is there any way to output content besides the <%= %> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

it seems that on Rails or erb, the only way to output anything is by <%=  %>

<% puts "hello" %> won't work, unlike PHP.

is there any other method at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concat will do:

```
<% concat ("wah ha ha!") %>
```

Reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001710

from the source code,

```
<% output_buffer << "hmm" %>
```

will work too and it is tested... but i think this is even lower level and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional response object does exist under the covers, and you *can* call response.write(str).  But a large part of the beauty of RoR is that this nuts and bolts stuff is abstracted away for you, and you don't have to do it.

Comment: why do you need to do this?  not criticising, just interested.